# How to mock function declaration in jest? I am getting Typescript error while mocking function declared as function declaration

Tags: typescript, jestjs

Everywhere I see mocking is done like this.

```
   foo = jest.fn(()=>{})
```

But it is ok only when the function is declared as function expression not as function declaration. When I do function declaration and try to mock that function like above I'm getting typescript error:

> TS2539: Cannot assign to 'foo' because it is not a variable.

Comment: What if you try `const foo = jest.fn()` ? ... presuming you haven't defined foo above in the scope

Comment: Doing it solves my problem. But as I'm new in testing, I'm not sure if it's ok for mocking and if in that case the function will be mocked.